# Static website cname problem, cloudfront

Tags: domain, cname-record, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Hey guys, one quick question. I've got a problem setting the cname for my domain http://snaremedia.com . I use godaddy and set the www cname to point at my cloudfront url, but currently my domain only work through entering www. and not without the www. How can I make sure my domain works whether or not the user enters www.

```
CNAME   www d2vga2hys6h3wj.cloudfront.net
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: did you find any solution..?

Answer (score 2):

add CNAME @ 2vga2hys6h3wj.cloudfront.net

Comment: I can't do that with GoDaddy for some reason, just doesn't work because @ by default points to the A record ip in goDaddy. I tried with another domain from another DNS service and cant get it working there either. http://buyout.dk vs www.buyout.dk